# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el ancho de una lista desplegable de JComboBox en java?

Tags: java, java-swing, combobox

necesito lograr esto :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

osea , un tamaño fijo para el jcombobox pero que la lista desplegable tome el tamaño del item mas grande que contenga. Tengo este código que funciona bien y hace lo que quiero :

```
public class WiderDropDownCombo extends JComboBox {

private String type;
private boolean layingOut = false;
private int widestLengh = 0;
private boolean wide = false;

public WiderDropDownCombo(Object[] objs) {
    super(objs);
}

public boolean isWide() {
    return wide;
}

// Setting the JComboBox wide
public void setWide(boolean wide) {
    this.wide = wide;
    widestLengh = getWidestItemWidth();

}

public Dimension getSize() {
    Dimension dim = super.getSize();
    if (!layingOut && isWide())
        dim.width = Math.max(widestLengh, dim.width);
    return dim;
}

public int getWidestItemWidth() {

    int numOfItems = this.getItemCount();
    Font font = this.getFont();
    FontMetrics metrics = this.getFontMetrics(font);
    int widest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfItems; i++) {
        Object item = this.getItemAt(i);
        int lineWidth = metrics.stringWidth(item.toString());
        widest = Math.max(widest, lineWidth);
    }

    return widest + 5;
}

public void doLayout() {
    try {
        layingOut = true;
        super.doLayout();
    } finally {
        layingOut = false;
    }
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String t) {
    type = t;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String title = "Combo Test";
    JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

    String[] items = {
            "I need lot of width to be visible , oh am I visible now",
            "I need lot of width to be visible , oh am I visible now" };
    WiderDropDownCombo simpleCombo = new WiderDropDownCombo(items);
    simpleCombo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 20));
    simpleCombo.setWide(true);
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Wider Drop Down Demo");

    frame.getContentPane().add(simpleCombo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    frame.getContentPane().add(label, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    int width = 200;
    int height = 150;
    frame.setSize(width, height);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

}

mostrandolo de esta forma :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me funciona en un ejemplo aparte. Yo tengo ya unos jcombobox creados y ubicados en mi programa , los cuales cargan sus item de una base de datos, pero no de la forma que lo hace el ejemplo anteriormente mostrado. Mi pregunta es la siguiente como puedo vincular el código del ejemplo que si funciona bien a mi código ? He intentado hacerlo de muchas maneras pero nada ha funcionado, si alguien tuviera alguna solución para mi seria de mucha ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una vez mas me debo responder mi misma pregunta :(
como sea, ya lo pude solucionar, y lo dejo plasmado acá para futuras dudas de otros usuarios.
Solo debes crear una clase java en blanco y copiar exactamente todo este código, quedando conformada la clase de esta forma:

```
public class BoundsPopupMenuListener implements PopupMenuListener {

private boolean scrollBarRequired = true;
private boolean popupWider;
private int maximumWidth = -1;
private boolean popupAbove;
private JScrollPane scrollPane;

/**
 * Convenience constructore to allow the display of a horizontal scrollbar
 * when required.
 */
public BoundsPopupMenuListener() {
    this(true, false, -1, false);
}

/**
 * Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup wider and/or
 * above the combo box.
 *
 * @param popupWider when true, popup width is based on the popup preferred
 * width
 * @param popupAbove when true, popup is displayed above the combobox
 */
public BoundsPopupMenuListener(boolean popupWider, boolean popupAbove) {
    this(true, popupWider, -1, popupAbove);
}

/**
 * Convenience constructor that allows you to display the popup wider than
 * the combo box and to specify the maximum width
 *
 * @param maximumWidth the maximum width of the popup. The popupAbove value
 * is set to "true".
 */
public BoundsPopupMenuListener(int maximumWidth) {
    this(true, true, maximumWidth, false);
}

/**
 * General purpose constructor to set all popup properties at once.
 *
 * @param scrollBarRequired display a horizontal scrollbar when the
 * preferred width of popup is greater than width of scrollPane.
 * @param popupWider display the popup at its preferred with
 * @param maximumWidth limit the popup width to the value specified (minimum
 * size will be the width of the combo box)
 * @param popupAbove display the popup above the combo box
 *
 */
public BoundsPopupMenuListener(
        boolean scrollBarRequired, boolean popupWider, int maximumWidth, boolean popupAbove) {
    setScrollBarRequired(scrollBarRequired);
    setPopupWider(popupWider);
    setMaximumWidth(maximumWidth);
    setPopupAbove(popupAbove);
}

/**
 * Return the maximum width of the popup.
 *
 * @return the maximumWidth value
 */
public int getMaximumWidth() {
    return maximumWidth;
}

/**
 * Set the maximum width for the popup. This value is only used when
 * setPopupWider( true ) has been specified. A value of -1 indicates that
 * there is no maximum.
 *
 * @param maximumWidth the maximum width of the popup
 */
public void setMaximumWidth(int maximumWidth) {
    this.maximumWidth = maximumWidth;
}

/**
 * Determine if the popup should be displayed above the combo box.
 *
 * @return the popupAbove value
 */
public boolean isPopupAbove() {
    return popupAbove;
}

/**
 * Change the location of the popup relative to the combo box.
 *
 * @param popupAbove true display popup above the combo box, false display
 * popup below the combo box.
 */
public void setPopupAbove(boolean popupAbove) {
    this.popupAbove = popupAbove;
}

/**
 * Determine if the popup might be displayed wider than the combo box
 *
 * @return the popupWider value
 */
public boolean isPopupWider() {
    return popupWider;
}

/**
 * Change the width of the popup to be the greater of the width of the combo
 * box or the preferred width of the popup. Normally the popup width is
 * always the same size as the combo box width.
 *
 * @param popupWider true adjust the width as required.
 */
public void setPopupWider(boolean popupWider) {
    this.popupWider = popupWider;
}

/**
 * Determine if the horizontal scroll bar might be required for the popup
 *
 * @return the scrollBarRequired value
 */
public boolean isScrollBarRequired() {
    return scrollBarRequired;
}

/**
 * For some reason the default implementation of the popup removes the
 * horizontal scrollBar from the popup scroll pane which can result in the
 * truncation of the rendered items in the popop. Adding a scrollBar back to
 * the scrollPane will allow horizontal scrolling if necessary.
 *
 * @param scrollBarRequired true add horizontal scrollBar to scrollPane
 * false remove the horizontal scrollBar
 */
public void setScrollBarRequired(boolean scrollBarRequired) {
    this.scrollBarRequired = scrollBarRequired;
}

/**
 * Alter the bounds of the popup just before it is made visible.
 */
@Override
public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) e.getSource();

    if (comboBox.getItemCount() == 0) {
        return;
    }

    final Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);

    if (child instanceof BasicComboPopup) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                customizePopup((BasicComboPopup) child);
            }
        });
    }
}

protected void customizePopup(BasicComboPopup popup) {
    scrollPane = getScrollPane(popup);

    if (popupWider) {
        popupWider(popup);
    }

    checkHorizontalScrollBar(popup);

    //  For some reason in JDK7 the popup will not display at its preferred
    //  width unless its location has been changed from its default
    //  (ie. for normal "pop down" shift the popup and reset)
    Component comboBox = popup.getInvoker();
    Point location = comboBox.getLocationOnScreen();

    if (popupAbove) {
        int height = popup.getPreferredSize().height;
        popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y - height);
    } else {
        int height = comboBox.getPreferredSize().height;
        popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height - 1);
        popup.setLocation(location.x, location.y + height);
    }
}

/*
 *  Adjust the width of the scrollpane used by the popup
 */
protected void popupWider(BasicComboPopup popup) {
    JList list = popup.getList();

    //  Determine the maximimum width to use:
    //  a) determine the popup preferred width
    //  b) limit width to the maximum if specified
    //  c) ensure width is not less than the scroll pane width
    int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width
            + 5 // make sure horizontal scrollbar doesn't appear
            + getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);

    if (maximumWidth != -1) {
        popupWidth = Math.min(popupWidth, maximumWidth);
    }

    Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
    popupWidth = Math.max(popupWidth, scrollPaneSize.width);

    //  Adjust the width
    scrollPaneSize.width = popupWidth;
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
    scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
}

/*
 *  This method is called every time:
 *  - to make sure the viewport is returned to its default position
 *  - to remove the horizontal scrollbar when it is not wanted
 */
private void checkHorizontalScrollBar(BasicComboPopup popup) {
    //  Reset the viewport to the left

    JViewport viewport = scrollPane.getViewport();
    Point p = viewport.getViewPosition();
    p.x = 0;
    viewport.setViewPosition(p);

    //  Remove the scrollbar so it is never painted
    if (!scrollBarRequired) {
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
        return;
    }

    //  Make sure a horizontal scrollbar exists in the scrollpane
    JScrollBar horizontal = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar();

    if (horizontal == null) {
        horizontal = new JScrollBar(JScrollBar.HORIZONTAL);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(horizontal);
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    }

    //  Potentially increase height of scroll pane to display the scrollbar
    if (horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(popup, scrollPane)) {
        Dimension scrollPaneSize = scrollPane.getPreferredSize();
        scrollPaneSize.height += horizontal.getPreferredSize().height;
        scrollPane.setPreferredSize(scrollPaneSize);
        scrollPane.setMaximumSize(scrollPaneSize);
        scrollPane.revalidate();
    }
}

/*
 *  Get the scroll pane used by the popup so its bounds can be adjusted
 */
protected JScrollPane getScrollPane(BasicComboPopup popup) {
    JList list = popup.getList();
    Container c = SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(JScrollPane.class, list);

    return (JScrollPane) c;
}

/*
 *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
 *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
 */
protected int getScrollBarWidth(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane) {
    int scrollBarWidth = 0;
    JComboBox comboBox = (JComboBox) popup.getInvoker();

    if (comboBox.getItemCount() > comboBox.getMaximumRowCount()) {
        JScrollBar vertical = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBarWidth = vertical.getPreferredSize().width;
    }

    return scrollBarWidth;
}

/*
 *  I can't find any property on the scrollBar to determine if it will be
 *  displayed or not so use brute force to determine this.
 */
protected boolean horizontalScrollBarWillBeVisible(BasicComboPopup popup, JScrollPane scrollPane) {
    JList list = popup.getList();
    int scrollBarWidth = getScrollBarWidth(popup, scrollPane);
    int popupWidth = list.getPreferredSize().width + scrollBarWidth;

    return popupWidth > scrollPane.getPreferredSize().width;
}

@Override
public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
    //  In its normal state the scrollpane does not have a scrollbar

    if (scrollPane != null) {
        scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBar(null);
    }
}
```

}

estas serian las librerias a importar :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.basic.*;
```

y listo, ahora , en la clase donde tienes ya el Jcombobox solo debes colocar lo siguiente debajo del inits() :

```
BoundsPopupMenuListener listener = new BoundsPopupMenuListener(true, false);
                nombre_combo.addPopupMenuListener( listener );
                nombre_combo.setPrototypeDisplayValue("ItemWWW");
```

y listo, asi tal cual va a funcionar, cabe resaltar que mi combo se llena automaticamente con datos de una base de datos y mas importante aun , creditos al autor verdadero de la info [link de la explicacion](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2010/11/28/combo-box-popup/)